# Does git add -A respect .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, git-add

I have several `target` subdirectories in my project that I do not want to track. So I removed them all with:

`find . -type d -name 'target' -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --cached -r --`

I also added `./*/target/` to my `.gitignore` file.

I then ran `git add -A` and it appears all of my `target` subdirectories were tracked and I had to remove them again.

Does `git add -A` simply not respect `.gitignore`? Will I have to run `git add` with a different option?

Comment: Had you previously committed these files? If so, this has been asked and answered a number of times already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: Yes but I removed them from the index with the aforementioned `find` command in the OP. If I run a `git commit` after removing them, the files are successfully untracked. It's only when I do `git add` after untracking the files that they get re-tracked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the incorrect format in my `.gitignore` file.

I replaced

```
./*/target/
```

with

```
*/target/**
```

`*/target/**` will recursively ignore all the contents of all `*/target` subdirectories.